# Qt web content with MinGW

Tags: mingw, qtwebengine, qt5.7

In newest Qt versions QtWebKit is no longer supported and was replaced by QtWebEngine which is based on Chromium. And Chromium can't be build with MinGW making QtWebEngine unavailable.

So, is there any way to use web content with Qt when using MinGW for compilation?

Answer (score 2):

Though not ideal it is possible to still compile and use the older community releases of QtWebKit e.g. http://download.qt.io/community_releases/5.6/5.6.0/qtwebkit-opensource-src-5.6.0.tar.gz works fine with qt5.7

For a more updated webkit https://github.com/annulen/webkit/releases/tag/qtwebkit-tp5 seems to be the best solution for now.